# Bootstrap 'align-content-around' not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Why is `align-content: space-around` not working here? What is the fix? Need to align columns 3 and 4 to bottom.

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">


      <div class="row align-content-around">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          4
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/y9perjhf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `row` has *auto* height - add `height: 100%` or `h-100` class to it - see demo below:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row align-content-around h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          1
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          2
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          3
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```